# Correct way to display my query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a query in my model that I need to print the data in my view

**Model**

```
    function get_bank()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT
(
   12* (YEAR('account_add_date') - YEAR('start_date')) +
          (MONTH('account_add_date') - MONTH('start_date'))
) AS differenceInMonth
->FROM ('bank')
WHERE mem_id = '".$this->session->userdata('id')."'");
return $query->result();
    $data['account_age'] =  $query->row_array();

    }
```

and I am trying to print the output in my model, but its not working and I do not know where I have gone wrong. I am new to MVC and still getting used to it.

**View**

```
 <h2>age of account</h2>

<?php
$age = $this->model('profiles_model' , $data );

print "<h2>$age</h2>";

?>
```

**Controller**

```
function index()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->load->model('user_profile/profiles_model');
        $query = $this->profiles_model->get_bank();


        if(!empty($query))
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }

        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }
```

Comment: That get_bank() method doesn't actually return anything. Is that intended?

Comment: so i should call get_bank in my view $this->model('get_bank') ?, one sec ill update my question

Comment: Are you using a MVC framework?

Comment: Hm, no. I think there is a return statement missing within the definition of `get_bank()`. Hence `$data['records']` will be empty in your controller and there is nothing in `$age` for the view to display.

Comment: @SamA yes Codeigniter

Comment: @DaSourcerer update my question to include return

Comment: Seems like the data is being put in  $data['records'] not $data.

Comment: even if i remove ['records'] and just put it in $data it still dose not read the $data in the view

Comment: Your function returns the query, the code afterwards does not get executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's first write your code in proper convention.

Model

```
function get_bank() {
    $mem_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $query = $this->db
        ->select("12*(YEAR('account_add_date') - YEAR('start_date')) + (MONTH('account_add_date') - MONTH('start_date')) AS differenceInMonth")
        ->where('mem_id', $mem_id)
        ->get('bank');

    return $query;
    // $data['account_age'] =  $query->row_array(); <-- Statement after return is useless.
}
```

Controller

```
function index() {
    $data = array(
        'records' => array()
    );
    $this->load->model('user_profile/profiles_model');
    $bank = $this->profiles_model->get_bank();

    if($bank->num_rows()){
        $data['records'] = $bank->row_array();
    }

    $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
}
```

View

Not sure what you are trying to do with the bank data but here's how you print the record

```
<p>Bank data</p>
<p><?=isset($records['differenceInMonth'])?$records['differenceInMonth']:"No record found"?></p>
```

Comment: @Beep Removed a line from model.

Comment: I'm not sure if the iteration in the view is really required. It seems there is going to be one result at most, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yea, it's not necessary. Updated.

Comment: Thanks guys am trying now

Comment: @Beep. Updated Controller to use row_array() instead of result_array() since it's a single row.

Comment: thank @komirad, still integrating it all in with my existing code, one ive done that and get it working. il accept your answer

Comment: @komirad & DaSourcerer, thanks for your help, is displaying now even if it is no records found, but that will be down to my query, il adjust accordingly. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You are not far away, do it this way:

Controller:

```
function index()
    {

        $this->load->model('user_profile/profiles_model');
        $data = $this->profiles_model->get_bank();

        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }
```

Model:

```
function get_bank()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT
          (
          12* (YEAR('account_add_date') - YEAR('start_date')) +
              (MONTH('account_add_date') - MONTH('start_date'))
           ) AS differenceInMonth
        ->FROM ('bank')
          WHERE mem_id = '".$this->session->userdata('id')."'");

         return $query->result();
    }
```

View:

```
<?php

foreach(differenceInMonth AS $age){

   echo "<p>" . $age . "</p>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks man, just trying out one of the earlier answer but if that dose notwork il try this one +1

Answer (score 0):

When you load the view you are passing in `$data` with `$data['records']` that has the data you are wanting to display.

Since that is how you pass the data into the view when you load it you will need to call it that way:

```
<?php
   var_dump($records);
?>
```

You will also need to loop through the data as well assuming $records is an array of the query results or use var_dump instead of print just to verify the data is there.

Reading through these will help going forward:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html